# JSP page with bean and <c:forEach> does not display when using ${ } but does with <%=%>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, javabeans

So if i try this

```
<c:forEach items="${beanArraylist}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
```

nothing is displayed but if i do this

```
<c:forEach items="<%= beanArraylist%>" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
```

it works and the items in the ArrayList are shown

I have no idea why it works with `<%= %>` but not with `${ }` anyone have any ideas.

EDIT: Showing Bean Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

public class BeanArraylist {
    ArrayList<BeanArrayListItem> bean;

    public BeanArrayList() {
        bean = new ArrayList<BeanArrayListItem>();
    }

    public void clearBeanArrayList() {
        bean = new ArrayList<BeanArrayListItem>();
    }

    public void insertBeanArrayList(BeanArrayListItem beanItem) {
        bean.add(beanItem);
    }

    public ArrayList getBeanArrayList() {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you are missing jstl import?

Comment: @Nambari. No that would show error on `<c:forEach` itself.

Comment: Show us your bean class, and getter and setter for `beanArraylist`.

Comment: You seem to be using JSF. If you didn't try those JSF bean management annotations randomly in a blind attempt to fix your problem, then it should work with `<c:forEach items="#{beanArrayList.beanArrayList}">`. If not, then you're indeed not using JSF at all and you should stop trying its annotations without actually understanding what you're doing. The following links may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 0):

ok so I figured it out. I had to add this line

`request.setAttribute("beanArraylist", bean);`

in my servlet. The servlet is where the `bean` object was created and the JSP page was called otherwise the `beanArraylist` was always empty in the JSP page when it was called in the `<c:forEach items="${beanArraylist}" var="item">` so nothing was there to output.

Comment: This answer is confusing. In your question you seem to have declared a JSF backing bean. Are you now using JSF or "plain vanilla" JSP/Servlet? Or were those JSF bean management annotations placed out of sheer of ignorance?

Comment: plain vanilla JSP/Servlet and yes the JSF bean management was a mistake i am just starting to learn. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: I posted some informal links in a comment to your question. Take your time to read it. When learning something, read a **real** and decent book/tutorial/resource instead of randomly googling solutions using possibly completely wrong keywords.